Aspire problem with the Azure Service Bus component
I've been trying to set up Aspire in a .NET Core solution that already uses Azure Service Bus for messaging. I followed the steps on this page but got the following error in the component-consuming project:
Failed to apply configuration value 'ConnectionStrings__Messaging'. A dependency may have failed to start.
In the App Host project, I got the following error as well:
Connection string parameter resource could not be used because connection string 'Messaging' is missing.
I can see the errors in the Logs section of the dashboard that Aspire provides when I run the App Host project.
In the startup of the component-consuming project I have the following lines:
builder.AddAzureServiceBusClient("Messaging");
In the appsettings.json, I have this setting:
"ConnectionStrings": { "Messaging": "Endpoint=sb://somenamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=Manage;SharedAccessKey=someaccesskey;EntityPath=topic1"},

And lastly, I got the following in the startup of the App Host project:
   var serviceBus = builder.AddConnectionString("Messaging");
   builder.AddProject<NotificationService>("notificationservice").WithReference(serviceBus);

What am I missing? Why are the projects unable to read the configured connection string?

Are you getting the issue locally?

Yes. Are you saying there a way to run the App Host project remotely?

I thought the issue is with the deployed app.Will check from my end.

Thanks. Can you confirm that Aspire works locally only? I mean can you deploy the App Host remotely to have the same dashboard or is the whole point of Aspire to help with local development?

@Harshitha what version of .NET Aspire are you using. Open up the AppHost.csproj file and share what version of the Aspire.Hosting.AppHost package you are using.

Here it is:


I have also gotten this exception and looking for a solution.  I'm assuming it's related to the fact that it doesn't know the actual service bus connection string.

Just an update, I just added the same ConnectionStrings section to the appsettings.json file in the App Host project and the error disappeared. The question is why would I need to do this? The connection string should be picked up from its original location in the component-consuming project.


Just an update, I just added the same ConnectionStrings section to the appsettings.json file in the App Host project and the error disappeared. The question is why would I need to do this? The connection string should be picked up from its original location in the component-consuming project.

In your AppHost project, you have the following code:
var serviceBus = builder.AddConnectionString("Messaging");
builder.AddProject<NotificationService>("notificationservice").WithReference(serviceBus);

This code is adding a "connection string" to your DistributedApplication (what your AppHost project is building up). This allows for multiple web app projects to consume the same connection information - you would call .AddReference(serviceBus) on multiple projects. It also allows you to switch this connection information out during deployment with azd, as it will prompt for a value.
The idea is that the AppHost is the coordinator of how the separate applications in your larger "distributed application" discover and connect to the other parts of the distributed application.
If you just want to configure your single web app project to talk directly to this Service Bus, you can remove the .AddConnectionString call in your AppHost, and configure the single project directly through its appSettings.json, or user secrets, like a regular ASP.NET Core app.
But adding the connection string to the AppHost (both in code, and setting a value in the AppHost configuration), is the more ".NET Aspire" way to do it.

Thanks. My understanding is .NET Aspire is a tool you run locally to set things up quickly like docker-compose or Tye and your solution should be able to be deployed without it (i.e. removing the App Host project shouldn't stop the solution from being deployed). Placing the connection string in the App Host (or any other dependencies for that matter) would be against this. Am I correct or should the App Host and its dashboard be part of the deployed package? One more question, with all this setup, should the Service Bus messages be traceable in the Aspire dashboard?

Reading the Azure Service Bus Component documentation, it seems these components use a slightly different structure in the appsettings.json. Instead of:
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
       "Messaging": ".... connection string ..."
   }
}

They use the format of Aspire:Azure:Messaging:ServiceBus or in Json:
{
   "Aspire": {
      "Azure": {
         "Messaging": {
            "ServiceBus": {
               "ConnectionString": "..."
            }  
         }
      }
   }
}


I tried that. It didn't work. I got the same error. Also, they really need to update the documentation. AddAzureServiceBus doesn't exists anymore and the alternative (AddAzureServiceBusClient) takes in a string and doesn't have any other overload without a parameter as suggested here.
